# Is it possible to turn an array into jQuery object?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Scenario: I'm logged in to an adminpanel. The adminanel is made in CodeIgniter.

I have a list of users

```
user1
user2
user3
etc...
```

Foreach user I have a hidden div with hidden information about them

something like

```
<a href="#">user1</a>
<div class="info" style="display:none;">
info about user1
</div>

<a href="#">user2</a>
<div class="info" style="display:none;">
info about user2
</div>

<a href="#">user3</a>
<div class="info" style="display:none;">
info about user3
</div>
```

etc...

Above is wrapped inside a form.

When I click for a user the nearest info-class-div shows. Information about each user should be editable and saved to the database.

```
<a class="moreinfo-user" href="#">User1</a>

<div class="info" style="display:none;">
    Namn:<input type="text" name="username">
    Phone:<input type="text" name="phone">
<input class="save-houseinfo" data-userid="<?php echo $user_id;?>" value="Save to db" />                          
</div>
```

First I thought I could a post-request, but then all names and phone(nrs) would be posted along with other stuff that is in the form in that seems such a waste.

**My code is currently** (jQuery):

```
$(".moreinfo-user").click(function(e){  

    //Save info for member      
    var user_id = $(this).attr('data-userid');    
    var parent_div = $(this).parent('.info');

    var info_name = parent_div.find('.house_name').val();
    var info_phone =  parent_div.find('.house_phone').val();


    var use_url = CI.base_url + 'membership/ajax_membership/quicksave/' 
        + encodeURIComponent(house_name) + '/' '
        + encodeURIComponent(house_phone);


    var saveInfo = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: use_url,                              
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    saveInfo.done(function(data) {
        alert('done');
        $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold').css('background', 'yellow').val('Sparat')
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(4000);
        alert(data);
    });

    saveInfo.fail(function(ts) {
        alert(ts.responseText);
    });

});
```

I'm unsure about how to send the data... This works...

```
var use_url = CI.base_url + 'membership/ajax_membership/quicksave/' 
            + encodeURIComponent(info_name) + '/' '
            + encodeURIComponent(info_phone);
```

But I would like to send a serialized object like this:

```
var info = {}
info.user_id = user_id;
info.name = info_name;
info.phone = info_phone;
var use_url =     var use_url = CI.base_url + 'membership/ajax_membership/quicksave/' 
                + info.serialize();
```

but then in console.log it says that serialize() is not a function. I figure that info isn't a jQuery object - that's why I get the error. Is there a way that info could be a converted into a jQuery object?

I just want to grap the data something like this in the controller:

```
public function quicksave($info_data) {
    //save stuff to db
    echo json_encode('saved info about user with user id ' . $info_data['user_id']);  
}
```

Comment: just use a javascript object

Comment: i think you can not `serialize()` an object like this from jQuery -> It can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual form controls, such as <input>, <textarea>, and <select>

Comment: @Ejay - how do you mean?

Comment: what if you use `data: info` in ajax request?

Comment: @Ejay - yeah. Of course. I was having the illussion you could only use data-parameter with post-requests (for some reason). Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You that set -1 - I would happily want to know why.

Comment: I didn't -1 (if you think it was me) but if I would do, it would be because of amount of code posted in question. You could make the question _really_ concise by focusing on "How to send variables in jquery ajax request", I think.

Comment: @Ejay - it's always "two sides of the coin". If I didn't post that much code then it might have been hard to understand why I wanted to convert the object... ...but I totally get what you mean. Thanks for your input! (and No I didn't actually think it was you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for  [`jQuery.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)

```
jQuery.param(info)
```

Comment: I will accept this as an answer because you do answer my question correctly. Even if I go for Ejays solution with data in ajax get request.